# How to set (upload) image to XMPP Group (room)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I want to set(upload) image to group and I'm struggling with my current code and not able to set image to group through xmpp.

```
- (void)updateAvatar:(UIImage *)profileImage
{
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage);

    helperAppDelegate *delegate = (helperAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [[delegate xmppvCardTempModule]myvCardTemp];
    if (myvCardTemp)
    {
        [myvCardTemp setPhoto:data];
        [[delegate xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp:myvCardTemp];
    }
    else
    {
        NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
        NSXMLElement *photoXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PHOTO"];
        NSXMLElement *typeXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"TYPE"stringValue:@"image/jpeg"];
        NSXMLElement *binvalXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"BINVAL" stringValue:[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength]];

        [photoXML addChild:typeXML];
        [photoXML addChild:binvalXML];
        [vCardXML addChild:photoXML];

        XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];

        [[delegate xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
    }
}
```